# fswatch write then delete

Tags: bash, unix, fswatch

I am using `fswatch` to refresh `refreshed.txt` when `watched.txt` is modified. Currently, `something` is appended to the `refreshed.txt`.

```
 fswatch -o watched.txt | xargs -n1 sh -c "echo 'something' >> refreshed.txt"
```

However, I want to write `something` and then delete it.

I have tried:

```
fswatch -o watched.txt | xargs -n1 sh -c "echo 'something\b\b' >> refreshed.txt"
```

and

```
fswatch -o watched.txt | xargs -n1 sh -c "echo 'something' >> refreshed.txt && sed -ie '$d' refreshed.txt"
```

but neither seem to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What _is_ the desired effect? Just to update the last modified date/time of `refreshed.txt`?

Comment: @RuudHelderman I think basically, yes. The `refreshed.txt` file is being watched by react-native for hot reloading purposes, so when it is modified, the app reloads. However, it's a pain having to manually remove all the newlines given by the first method, so just wanted to see if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Just `touch` your refreshed.txt file: `touch refreshed.txt` to update it's modification timestamp.

Comment: @zeppelin yep that's the first thing I tried, but for whatever reason it's not picked up by react-native and so the app does not refresh when using that method.

Comment: @ColinRicardo It must be tracking the file size (or checksum) then. But adding some data and then immediately removing it, won't be of much help in this case, as all that will remain at the end is the modified timestamp.

Comment: @zeppelin that may be the case, but the issue here is when I run either of the last two code chunks above, the `refreshed.txt` file only gets newlines appended to it, with no deletion taking place. So, the question is: why is `sed` not being run?

Comment: @ColinRicardo The sed is not run, because when you feed you `"` quoted script to sh, `$d` is replaced with an empty string: `sed -ie '' refreshed.txt`

Comment: Just replace `sh -c`, with `echo` to see the resulting command.
You should escape `$`, to avoid that: `sed  -ie '\$d' refreshed.txt`

Comment: @zeppelin while this doesn't fix the hot reloading problem, this does work as intended. If you want to write an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: "It's a pain having to manually remove all the newlines..." Why are newlines inside `refreshed.txt` a problem? If the content of that file is important, then exactly what is the desired content? `echo 'something\b\b'` suggests you are trying to append a string without trailing newline; if so, then try `echo -n something`.

Comment: @RuudHelderman adding a newline for every change in the `watched` file leads to hundreds of newlines, the existence of which is easy to forget about, and leads to them being pushed to GitHub, etc. I'd rather just not have to manually remove them. The file itself should remain unchanged content-wise, but since `touch` and Zepellin's solution don't trigger reloading, I'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear `refreshed.txt` is under source control (i.e. subject to being pushed to GitHub). If a file's contents are _that_ important to you, then you should not be using that particular file to trigger events at runtime. I would suggest to start using a whole new file for react-native to watch, and let `fswatch` populate it with a timestamp: `date > refreshed_2.txt`

Comment: @RuudHelderman yep you're right. That's a good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed is not run, because when you feed you `"` quoted script to `sh`, $d is replaced with an empty string:

```
sed -ie '' refreshed.txt.
```

You should escape `$`, to avoid that:

```
sed -ie '\$d' refreshed.txt
```

Note that adding a line and then immediately removing it, 
would be pretty much an equivalent of simply updating it's modification timestamp, so you may want to make it sleep for a bit, for the change detection system to catch on.